# How to add field name in python in arcgis?

Tags: python-3.x, arcgis

I am making one tool, and for this I want to save result of this tool in field that I've added. I want give name to that field on the basis of amenity selection (Here I've given data type of amenity as string. and added a list of values in amenity parameter like Education, Medical, Transportation, etc.). If I select "education" from amenities then my field name is like "Edu_IC". How can I do this? I've added my code snippet below

```
def setupVulnerability():
    GP = ARC.create(9.3)     
    print(SYS.version)


    InputFC = GP.GetParameterAsText(0) # Input Feature Class
    print "InputFC:-'%s'" % (InputFC)

    Fields = GP.GetParameterAsText(1)
    print "Fields:-'%s'" % (Fields)

    fieldList = Fields.split(";")
    print "fieldList:-'%s'" % (fieldList)

    amenity = GP.GetParameterAsText(2)
    print "amen:-'%s'" % (amenity)



    all_field_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(InputFC)]

    field_Name = None
    try:
          for field in fieldList:
            field_Name = field[0:3]+ "_" + "IC"
            if field_Name in all_field_names:
                continue
            else :
                GP.AddField(InputFC , field_Name , "FLOAT")
            field_Name = None
    except:
        raise ERROR.ScriptError()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setupVulnerability()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that your "amenity" variable, which receives input from the user, is not referenced when the field is being added.

Something like this should work:

```js
amenity = GP.GetParameterAsText(2)
if amenity == "Education":
    field_name = amenity[:3] + "_IC"
    GP.AddField(InputFC, field_Name, "FLOAT")
```